# Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sell(head, body, image_id, image_id_2, image_id_3, `image_id_4`) VALUES ($head, $body, $image_id, $image_id_2, $image_id_3, $image_id_4)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Выдает ошибку Unknown column 'test1' in 'field list', где test1 это содержимое переменной $head

Comment: Надо квотриовать - добавлять кавычки для строк. Иначе он думает что это название столбца. Например `VALUES ('$head',`

Answer (score 0):

Например я привык писать все запросы так:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO sell(`head`, `body`, `image_id`, `image_id_2`,`image_id_3`, `image_id_4`) VALUES ('$head', '$body', '$image_id', '$image_id_2','$image_id_3', '$image_id_4')") or die(mysql_error());
```